How do I effectively compute pairwise quantities in numpy?
I want to compute pairwise quantities, e.g. distances between two points.
A simple example would be
import numpy as np

N = 9
x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
y = np.abs(x - x[:,None]) # pairwise 1d eucdlidian distance

This will result in an (N,N) array, that holds the distances from every element in x to every other element in x.
However, one can discard the lower (or upper) triangle of y, since the distance from x[0] to x[1] is the same as the distance from x[1] to x[0].
Can anyone think of a way of never computing the lower (or upper) triangle in the first place? Ideally this would generalize to Nd arrays, e.g.
x = np.linspace(0,1,N)
y = x + (1j * x)[:,None] # complex plane
z = np.abs(y[:,:,None,None] - y[None,None,:,:]) # pairwise 2d euclidian distance

and any pairwise quantity, e.g.
y = np.random.randint(0,2,(N,N))
z = y[:,:,None,None] == y[None,None,:,:] # pairwise equality

Thanks in advance.
PS: For anyone interested, this came up when I tried implementing an energy function for 2d simulated annealing.

The generic method provided by numpy for this is ufunc.outer. However, it is not clear whether this skips processing of the lower triangular part, or even if it makes it faster. It also does not support custom calculations such as Euclidean distance. As a more general method, you might want to use numba.

Manually
You could generate the pair of indices with itertools.combinations and manually compute the distances:
from itertools import combinations

a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(range(len(x)), 2)))

tri = abs(x[a]-x[b])

Output:
array([0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 1.   , 0.125,
       0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375,
       0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.125,
       0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.125, 0.25 , 0.125])

Which are the distance between the indices:
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 2),
 (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5),
 (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 5),
 (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)]

Using scipy.spatial.distance.pdist
This is exactly what pdist is doing:
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

tri = pdist(x[:, None]) # one needs a 2D input

Output:
array([0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 1.   , 0.125,
       0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375,
       0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.125,
       0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.125, 0.25 , 0.125])

NB. the order of the pairs is the same as in the itertools.combinations approach.
If you want to get the squareform:
squareform(tri)

array([[0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875, 1.   ],
       [0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 , 0.875],
       [0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625, 0.75 ],
       [0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  , 0.625],
       [0.5  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375, 0.5  ],
       [0.625, 0.5  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 , 0.375],
       [0.75 , 0.625, 0.5  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125, 0.25 ],
       [0.875, 0.75 , 0.625, 0.5  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.125],
       [1.   , 0.875, 0.75 , 0.625, 0.5  , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.125, 0.   ]])

ND-arrays
NB. This does not generalize directly to ND arrays, but might be able to temporarily reshape to 2D depending on the exact use case.
In your second example, you could use:
# pairwise distances
tri = pdist(y.reshape(-1, 1))

# square form
out = squareform(tri).reshape(9, 9, 9, 9)

Unfortunately, pdist doesn't seem to handle complex data.

The manual implementation using itertools.combinations seems to be the versatile, general and easy to use solution I was hoping for. I'll test it and if it works will accept your answer. I'd suggest moving it to the top of your answer, because the other solutions are more specific and require additional installations.
